# How to get value in the struct field in spark?

Tags: python, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I'm beginning in Spark and I would like to understand how to access the value in struct fields in Spark.
How many ways do we have to do it, for example, to access the product_name and product_category values?

I don't know, but I've read that explode command performs poorly when it needs to work with thousands of data.

Best Regards,

Thank you so much.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, LongType, StringType, FloatType, ArrayType


input_data = [(("Refrigerator", 112345, "Eletronico"), 4.0, 12499),
                  (("LED TV", 114567, "Eletronico"), 4.2, 49999),
                  (("Washing Machine", 113465, "Eletronico"), 3.9, 69999),
                  (("T-shirt", 124378, "Vestuario"), 4.1, 1999),
                  (("Jeans", 126754, "Vestuario"), 3.7, 3999),
                  (("Running Shoes", 134565, "Vestuario"), 4.7, 1499),
                  (("Face Mask", 145234, "Outros"), 4.6, 999)]

schm = StructType([
        StructField('Product', StructType([
            StructField('Product_name', StringType(), True),
            StructField('Product_ID', LongType(), True),
            StructField('Product_category', StringType(), True),            
        ])),

        StructField('Rating', FloatType(), True),
        StructField('Price', IntegerType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=input_data, schema = schm)


df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dot, `.`, notation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=input_data, schema = schm)

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('product_name', f.col('Product.Product_name'))
    .withColumn('product_category', f.col('Product.Product_category'))
)
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

And the output looks like:

```
+--------------------+------+-----+---------------+----------------+            
|             Product|Rating|Price|   product_name|product_category|
+--------------------+------+-----+---------------+----------------+
|{Refrigerator, 11...|   4.0|12499|   Refrigerator|      Eletronico|
|{LED TV, 114567, ...|   4.2|49999|         LED TV|      Eletronico|
|{Washing Machine,...|   3.9|69999|Washing Machine|      Eletronico|
|{T-shirt, 124378,...|   4.1| 1999|        T-shirt|       Vestuario|
|{Jeans, 126754, V...|   3.7| 3999|          Jeans|       Vestuario|
|{Running Shoes, 1...|   4.7| 1499|  Running Shoes|       Vestuario|
|{Face Mask, 14523...|   4.6|  999|      Face Mask|          Outros|
+--------------------+------+-----+---------------+----------------+

root
 |-- Product: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Product_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Product_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Product_category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Rating: float (nullable = true)
 |-- Price: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- product_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product_category: string (nullable = true)
```